# Read multiple files from Databricks DBFS

Tags: python, databricks

I've started to work with Databricks python notebooks recently and can't understand how to read multiple `.csv` files from DBFS as I did in Jupyter notebooks earlier.

I've tried:

```
path = r'dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/path/' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, low_memory=False)
    li.append(df)

data = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

This code worked perfectly in Jupyter notebooks, but in Databricks, I receive this error:
`ValueError: No objects to concatenate`

I can reach one file in this path using `df = pd.read_csv('dbfs_path/filename.csv')`

Thanks!

Comment: You can print the filename which error happened, and check the file is right(Open it separately)

Comment: @Vassago I can literally open any file in the folder by using `pd.read_csv()` in another chunk, but I can't open any in my for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `path` to  `r'/dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/path/'`

The `glob` function will work with the raw filesystem attached to the driver, and has no notion of what `dbfs:` means.

Also, since you are combining a lot of csv files, why not read them in directly with spark:

```
path = r'dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/path/*.csv' 
df = spark.read.csv(path)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are reading DBFS location , we should read through `dbutils` command as like this .

```
files = dbutils.fs.ls('/FileStore/shared_uploads/path/')
li = []
for fi in files: 
  print(fi.path)
  <your logic here>
```